# WKWebview sometimes display img just a half

Tags: html, iphone

[this a normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXLkI.png)

[this img display just a half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxgUP.png)
the WKWebview into tableViewCell.when WKWebview didfinishload ,then update tableviewcell height.sometimes the img display a half,i'm sure the cell height is right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' charset=''/>
<body>

<p>
    <img src="http://resources.ovuwork.com/userfiles/static/upload/image/20160926/1474890263272044686.png"
         title="1474890263272044686.png"
         style="width:100%"
         alt="space_index_img_space.png"/>
</p>
</body>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' charset=''/>
<body>

<p>
    <img src="http://resources.ovuwork.com/userfiles/static/upload/image/20160926/1474890263272044686.png"
         title="1474890263272044686.png"
         style="width:100%"
         alt="space_index_img_space.png"/>
</p>
</body>
```

```html
HTML content:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' charset=''/>
<body>

<p>
    <img src="http://resources.ovuwork.com/userfiles/static/upload/image/20160926/1474890263272044686.png"
         title="1474890263272044686.png"
         style="width:100%"
         alt="space_index_img_space.png"/>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: when display just a half,double click wkwebview,the img will display all.how can I fix it to display all everytime?